# how to compare id of html element inside of a map function with the id of an object outside of the map function

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have been trying to find a way to compare the id of an HTML element inside of the map function with the id of an object outside the map function. I'm looking for some guidance on how to do this and what the best practice is. When post 1 is clicked It should only show post 1. I've put together a simple example so it is easy to see what I'm trying to do.

In the filter method how do I make the comparison of id of element clicked and id that matches from the posts array of objects.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
       this.showPost = this.showPost.bind(this),      

    this.state = {

      posts: [{
          question: 'post 1',
        body: 'BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH',
        postType: 'Question',
        Id: 123,
      },
      {
          question: 'post 2',
        body: 'BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH',
        postType: 'Question',    
        Id: 133,
      },
      ],

      openedPost: false,

    };
  }

showPost() {
  console.log("post shown");
  this.setState({ openedPost: true });
}

  render() {
    const posts = this.state.posts.map((item) => 
    <div key={item.Id}> 
      <h1 Id={item.Id} onClick={this.showPost}> {item.question} </h1> 
    </div>
        )
      if(this.state.openedPost) {
       const clickedPost = this.state.posts.filter(function(item) {
           return 
    })

      }
    return (
      <div>
      {posts}
      {clickedPost}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

[project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zwgerk?embed=1&file=index.js)

Comment: check this updated [project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-sxnhyh?file=index.js) (comments included)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing an `id` as a `DOM` attribute and reading it back from the `DOM`, i recommend to do it with components (this is the react way in my opinion).

Let `react` deal and "touch" the `DOM` and let it do it's magic with [The Diffing Algorithm and Reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html)

You should create a `<Post />` component that can accept a `postId` as a prop, as well as an `onClick` handler that can invoke the parent's handler and pass it the relevant `postId`.

A running example:

```js
class Post extends React.Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    const { postId, onClick } = this.props;
    onClick(postId);
  }

  render() {
    const { question } = this.props;
    return (
      <div onClick={this.handleClick}>
        <h1>
          {question}
        </h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.showPost = this.showPost.bind(this),

      this.state = {
        posts: [{
          question: 'post 1',
          body: '1: BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH',
          postType: 'Question',
          Id: 123,
        },
        {
          question: 'post 2',
          body: '2: BLAH BLAH BLAH BLAH',
          postType: 'Question',
          Id: 133,
        }],
        openedPost: null
      };
  }

  showPost = (postId) => {
    console.log("post shown id:" + postId);
    this.setState({ openedPost: postId });
  }

  renderPosts = () => {
    const { posts } = this.state;
    return posts.map(post => <Post key={post.Id} onClick={this.showPost} question={post.question} postId={post.Id} />);
  }

  render() {
    const { posts, openedPost } = this.state;
    const rendredPosts = this.renderPosts();
    const clickedPost = openedPost && posts.find(item => item.Id == this.state.openedPost).body;

    return (
      <div>
        {rendredPosts}
        {clickedPost}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

**Edit**
As a followup to your comment:

> so in
>
> ```
> return posts.map(post => <Post key={post.Id} onClick={this.showPost} question={post.question} postId={post.Id} />);
> ```
>
> we dont have to pass an Id into `this.showPost` can you explain exactly
>   how it knows to grab the id of that specific element?

This method returns an array of `<Post/>` component, this component can get a prop of `postId` (you can name it whatever you like). It also get a prop of an `onClick` callback as you know.
Inside this component we have an internal `handleClick` handler that invoking the callback passed from the parent and invoking it while passing it the verry same `props.postId` the parent passed.

```
  handleClick = () => {
     // see here we use both the onClick and postId props passed by the parent
    const { postId, onClick } = this.props;
    onClick(postId);
  }
```

> See this is where I'm struggling to understand. Why wouldnt we pass
>   item.Id into that, how does it automatically know to grab the id of
>   the one clicked?

So i hope now you understand that we did in fact passed the `post.Id` but not to the `onClick` callback directly, instead we pass it to the component as a prop `itemId`, and the component invoked the `onClick` with this prop via `this.props.itemId`.

In `react` the data (**should**) flow in a uni-directional way.
Parents pass data to children via `props` (or `context`).

Sometimes though,  we need to pass data back from the child to the parent. Like in your case, the child should pass its ID when clicked.
The way to do that is using callbacks. The parent pass a callback to the child and its the child's responsibility to invoke this method and inject some data to it.

When you pass a callback to a `DOM` element you can't pass any data back, as the `DOM` element is not a component you control. the only data that comes back is the `event` of the trigger (the click event in this case) and you can access the target of this event, that is the real `DOM` element that triggered the click event and grab attributes from it, like the `id`.
This is a bad practice as i mentioned above with [The Diffing Algorithm and Reconciliation](https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html).

#### So what is the solution and proper way of doing this?

**Take control of your elements by composing components.**

With components you can do some logic or decide when and how handlers will get invoked, what kind of data they will pass and of course you can reuse them and test them!

I hope that answered your questions and helped you understand a bit more about it.

Comment: what do you do if you want to render more than just .body?

Comment: `const body = openedPost && posts.find(item => item.Id == this.state.openedPost).body;
    const image  = openedPost && posts.find(item => item.Id == this.state.openedPost).imgSrc;
    const type  = openedPost && posts.find(item => item.Id == this.state.openedPost).postType;
    const question = openedPost && posts.find(item => item.Id == this.state.openedPost).question;` I did it like this because I wanted to be able to style each element is their a better implementation? @Sag1v

Comment: You can create another component, someting like `<PostDetails />` that will get a post object and show all of its content

Comment: Hey @Sag1v so in `return posts.map(post => <Post key={post.Id} onClick={this.showPost} question={post.question} postId={post.Id} />);` we dont have to pass an Id into `this.showPost` can you explain exactly how it knows to grab the id of that specific element? See this is where I'm struggling to understand. Why wouldnt we pass item.Id into that, how does it automatically know to grab the id of the one clicked? When I look at the method `showPost = (postId) => {
    console.log("post shown id:" + postId);
    this.setState({ openedPost: postId });
  }` it takes an id so help me understand.

Comment: @Omar I've edited my answer to answer some of your comments

Comment: the updated answer clarified my questions. I wanted to ask one more thing `const clickedPost = openedPost && posts.find(item => item.Id == this.state.openedPost).body;
` is it better to use `const filteredPosts = posts.filter(function(item){
        return openedPost == item.Id;
    })` Now I can map through the post that is clicked in render, and style it how I'd like. Is there anything wrong with displaying it this way, in using `filter` instead of `find`?

Comment: [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) returns the first value (the first post object in your case) where [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) will return a new array (an array with a single post object in your case).

Answer (score 0):

I would store which `post` was clicked in the `showPost` method.

```
showPost(event){
  const clickedPost = this.state.posts.find( // .find is not supported in IE
    post=>post.id===event.target.id
  )
  this.setState({clickedPost})
}
```